# Prove or disprove: The sequence has only got one cluster point if...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, clustering

> Prove or disprove: The sequence $(x_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with
>   $a_{k}=\frac{1}{k}$ if $k\in\mathbb{N}$ odd and $a_{k}=1$ if
>   $k\in\mathbb{N}$ even, has only got one cluster point.

I say the statement is true because both the given sequences (odd / even) can only have 1 cluster point and so choosing one of these, we will end up with one cluster point.

Is it right or not?

Comment: It's not.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What are the limits of the two subsequences (odd $k$; even $k$)? Are they equal? That should give you your answer.

Comment: Limit of odd is $0$ and the cluster point is $0$ as well. For the even one it's $1$, limit and cluster point. I cannot see more than 1 cluster point here then.

Comment: If you would, please provide your definition for a cluster point. It may illuminate the confusion.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that *"a sequence can have only one cluster point"*.  This is not the case.  It is the case, however, that a sequence can only have one *limit*, and a limit of a sequence is also a cluster point.

Comment: If we take $(-1)^{k}$, this would have 2 cluster points, right? And no limit..

Comment: That's right.  Just as that sequence has cluster points $-1$ and $1$, so does your sequence have cluster points $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Oh now things make sense for me :-)
Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsequence of odd $a_k$ has limit $0$, which is a cluster point of the of overall sequence $(a_k)$.  The subsequence of even $a_k$ has limit $1$, which is a cluster point of the overall sequence $(a_k)$.  We therefore conclude that the sequence $(a_k)$ has two cluster points: $0$ and $1$.

What we do *not* say is that "we can choose one of these cluster points to get a one cluster point, so the sequence has only one cluster point".  There is no place in mathematics where one counts things in this way.

Comment: Damn it's really not easy for me to understand tasks like that. I understand the details, like how many cluster points a sequence has, here for these odd and even. But the conclusion... Anyway thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Disprove by considering two subsequences of {$a_n$}:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}${$a_{2n}$}$=1$   and
 $\lim_{n\to\infty}${$a_{2n+1}$}$=0$.
Since the limit of these 2 subsequences are different, therefore {$a_n$} will not converge to one cluster point.